# Where has Tracker.CurrentVisit.Profiles migrated to?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I see a lot of examples around where people are using `Tracker.CurrentVisit.Profiles` in their code.

Those examples seem to be using older versions of Sitecore.

Does anyone know where that collection has migrated to in later versions of Sitecore (i.e. v8.2)?

Comment: Looking for this: Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles ?

Comment: Or this? `Tracker.Current.Contact.BehaviorProfiles`?

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to "sniff-out" `Tracker.Current.Contact.BehaviorProfiles.Profiles`, but I'm nut not sure that I'm getting the same collection back that the examples I'm looking at use.

Comment: @Gatogordo - I think your comment is the right one. Looks consistent with what Ian Graham has written in [this post](http://www.coreblimeysitecore.com/blog/where-did-dms-go-in-sitecore-8/ "read post")

Answer (score 2):

Considering that a `Visitor` became a `Contact` and a `Visit` is now called an  `Interaction` I would assume you are looking for `Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles`.

As you mentioned, a bit more information in [this post](http://www.coreblimeysitecore.com/blog/where-did-dms-go-in-sitecore-8/) from Ian.

Comment: What is the difference between `Interaction.Profiles` and `Contact.BehaviorProfiles`?

Comment: The `Interaction.Profiles` is about the current interaction, the `Contact.BehaviorProfiles` is about the contact (can be multiple interactions). This is an assumption though - just as I assume the BehaviorProfiles comes from the BehaviorCache.

Comment: One problem with the Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles is that it is not interable.

Comment: It would be nice to get some official feedback from Sitecore, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: You can always ask Support - but I'm rather sure about the assumptions made.

Comment: BehaviorProfiles is like the historical data of the contact after the merge process has been done. That is, when the session end for a user, sitecore update the behaviorProfile by merging the data captured during the session with the historical data. If I am not mistaken, it will also update the user pattern card